# HttpContent.CopyToAsync for large files

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, filestream, .net-core-2.1

Hope you're all doing well!

Lets say I'm downloading a file from an HTTP API endpoint and file size is quite large. API returns `application/octet-stream` i.e. `HttpContent` in my download method.

when I use

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStrean(somepath, FileMode.Create))
{
    // this operation takes a few seconds to write to disk
    await httpContent.CopyToAsync(fs); 
}
```

As soon as the using statement is executed - I see the file created on the file system at given path, although it is 0 KB at this point, but when `CopyToAsync()` finishes executing, file size is as expected.

Problem is there's another service running which is constantly polling the folder where above files are saved and often times 0 KB are picked up or sometimes even partial files (this seems to be the case when I use `WriteAsync(bytes[])`.

Is there a way to not save the file on file system until its ready to be saved...?

One weird work around I could think of was:

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await httpContent.CopyToAsync(memStream);
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(destFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        memStream.Position = 0;
        await memStream.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
}
```

I copy the HttpContent over to a `MemoryStream` and then copy the memorystream over to FileStream... this seems to have worked but there's a cost to memory consumption...

Another work around I could think of was to first save the files into a secondary location and when operation is complete, Move the file over to Primary folder.

Thank you in Advance,

Johny

Comment: You may copy it to another intermediate folder, then move it to the target folder once download is finished. Moving file is atomic operation.

Comment: @Renat Yes, that's what I'm leaning towards as you can see in my original post*. That will most definitely work :)

Comment: @Johny keeping whole files in memory if they are large is not a very good idea. Temporary folder/file(so you pick file which don't end with ".tmp" for example) or some locking/messaging mechanism should be better.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for your comment. Yes that's exactly the reason why I'm not comfortable with this approach. As for the .tmp, see I was actually thinking that's how it should save the file until Copy task is complete but it actually drops 0 KB files as original extensions like .pdf etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving the file into a temporary folder and when the operation is complete, I move the downloaded file to my primary folder. Since Move is atomic I do not have this issue anymore.

Thank you for those who commented!